# Vb.net assign value by ref?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say i have a textbox and a string, i want to make it that the textboxes text attribute always reflects whats written in the string without assigning it every time the string changes.

Is it possible to override the textboxes draw function to fetch the value from a.. pointer(for lack of a better word)? Also can i override an object instances function without creating a new inheriting class?

Also why does this board insist on me using proper grammar for things like the textbox object? In my opinion it would just make the post more confusing.

Comment: show the code you have ..

Comment: it's a hypothetical question

Comment: So you want the TextBox contents to be automagically updated whenever the string is changed?  Not saying it can't be done, just want to make sure I understand your question.  As far as overriding an object's instance functions, I'm 99% sure they have to be marked as virtual (overridable in VB.NET I think), though you could probably work around it. Your third point is very confusing - what do you mean by insisting on proper grammar?

Comment: It wouldn't let me post until i added that last paragraph, underlined the textboxes and said i need to use proper grammar.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  What is the reason behind attempting this?  There might be an entirely different approach if we know what the purpose is.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont work, even if you managed to override properties.

Strings in .NET are immutable objects, any modification to a string results in creating a new string object and modifying the initial "pointer" to the new object.

```
string x = "foo";
string y = x;

x = "bar";

Console.WriteLine(y); //Prints "foo"
```